# Power BI Analysis Services Data Source username and password

Tags: powerbi, analysisservices

I have trouble with Power BI when I want to add an Analysis Services Data Source:

[image]

I don't know what the username and password are. When I want to connect, I use Windows authentication which has no need for a username and password.

Answer (score 1):

Use your Windows username and password. Then, you need to use an "Effective Username" to map it with your connection. More details here :[SSAS Refresh in PowerBI](https://pbiwebprod-docs.azurewebsites.net/en-us/documentation/powerbi-gateway-enterprise-manage-ssas/#add-a-data-source).

Comment: windows username? do you mean email?

Comment: The username and password that you use to login to windows.

Comment: sorry, i don't get it

Comment: When you connect to your analysis services, you don't use any username or password. Because it gets connected through windows authentication. Right? What I am saying is use the same Windows Account login ID and password to connect.

Comment: do you mean my desktop account or microsoft account?